# Getting attribute from simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to figure out how to load the variable location,, time and val from the following XML.

The XML looks like this:

```
<root xmlns="">
     <sns id="1" name="Senzor A" type="1" status="0" unit="0" val="4.5" w-min="" w-max=""/>
     <status level="2" location="AAA" time="03/21/2018 14:09:08"/>
</root>
```

Parsed XML looks like this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["sns"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(8) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "Senzor A"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["unit"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["val"]=>
      string(3) "4.5"
      ["w-min"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["w-max"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["status"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["level"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["location"]=>
      string(3) "AAA"
      ["time"]=>
      string(19) "03/21/2018 14:09:08"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to navigate, so if anyone could throw me some pointers I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing attributes with simpleXML can be done using `$tag['attribute_name']`.

Accessing elements can be done using `$xml->tag` or `$xml->tag->subtag`.

```
$xml = '<root xmlns="">
<sns id="1" name="Senzor A" type="1" status="0" unit="0" val="4.5" w-min="" w-max=""/>
<status level="2" location="AAA" time="03/21/2018 14:09:08"/>
</root>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); // or simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
echo $xml->status['location'];
echo $xml->status['time'];
echo $xml->sns['val'];
```

Outputs:

```
AAA
03/21/2018 14:09:08
4.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been overcomplicating things, but doing more levels in the $xml-> path.

Comment: @arvestrid You can access it using `$xml->tag->subtag`.